# (JavaFX) Display double value as a progressBar

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar

I'm having an issue getting my progressBar to display a double value. I'd like the bar to decrease as the height of an object goes down and the fuel bar to decrease as a button is being held down.

```
    @FXML
    private ProgressBar progFuel; //Progress Bar to represent the remaining 
    fuel
    @FXML
    private ProgressBar progHeight; //Progress Bar to represent the altitude 
    of the ship

    private void onTimer() {
    /**
     * Method to calculate fuel,velocity,gravity,height sets the initial
     * height of the lander's height sets the initial fuel of the lander to 100%
     */
    progHeight.setProgress(INITIAL_HEIGHT);
    progFuel.setProgress(1.0);

    pe.nextStep(btnThrust.isPressed()); //calls the nextStep method from PhysicsEngine; passes pressed state of Thrust Button
    progFuel.setProgress(pe.getFuel());
    progHeight.setProgress(pe.getHeight());

    /**
     * Sets the string value of velocity and height to corresponding TextFields
     */
    _txtVelocity.setText(String.valueOf(pe.getVelocity()));
    _txtHeight.setText(String.valueOf(pe.getHeight()));

    progFuel.setStyle("-fx-accent: green"); //sets color of Fuel Progress Bar to green
```

This is where the calculations for height and fuel are made:

```
public class PhysicsEngine {

    public static final double GRAVITY = -1.622;  // The acceleration due to gravity on the moon in meters per second per second (m/s/s), negative means down

    public static final double THRUST_STRENGTH = 5.0;  // The strength of the lander's rocket in meters per second per second (m/s/s)

    public static final double INITIAL_HEIGHT = 500;   // The initial height in meters (m). The real Apollo 11 lunar module started powered descent at height 11853 m.

    public static final double SAFE_LANDING_SPEED = 5.0;   // The safe landing speed below which we don't crash in meters per second (m/s)

    public static final double TIME_STEP = 0.1;        // The size of each step in the simulation, in seconds (s)


    private double _height;       // The lander's current height in meters, height of zero means the simulation is stopped

    private double _vel;          // The lander's current velocity in meters per second, negative means moving down

    private double _fuel;         // The amount of fuel remaining as a percent, where 100 means full and 0 means empty

    private double _elapsedTime;  // The simulation elapsed time in seconds

    /**
     * Getter for height.
     * @return The lander's height in meters (m).
     */
    public double getHeight() {
        return _height;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for velocity.
     * @return The lander's velocity in meters per second (m/s), where positive means up and negative means down.
     */
    public double getVelocity() {
        return _vel;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for fuel amount.
     * @return The amount of fuel remaining as a percent.
     */
    public double getFuel() {
        return _fuel;
    }

    /**
     * Getter for elapsed time.
     * @return The simulation elapsed time in seconds.
     */
    public double getElapsedTime() {
        return _elapsedTime;
    }


    /**
     * Starts the simulation by setting initial conditions.
     */
    public void start() {
        _elapsedTime = 0;
        _vel = 0;
        _height = INITIAL_HEIGHT;
        _fuel = 100;
    }

    /**
     * Calculates the lander's height and velocity for the next step in the simulation.
     * In each step this method updates
     * - The lunar lander's velocity, based on engine thrust and gravity
     * - The lander's height, based on velocity
     * - The lander's fuel amount, based on thrust
     * @param thrust true means the lander's rocket is firing, false means not firing.
     * @return true if the simulation is finished (lander has landed), false if simulation is still running.
     */
    public boolean nextStep(boolean thrust) {
        boolean result = false;      // The value to return from this method, false unless set otherwise

        // Return immediately if simulation is already stopped
        if (_height <= 0) {
            return result;
        }

        // If there is fuel left then apply thrust from the engine and decrease the fuel amount
        double actualThrust = 0;
        if (_fuel > 0 && thrust) {
            actualThrust = THRUST_STRENGTH;
            _fuel -= actualThrust/7.5;    // Decrease the amount of fuel, engine is thrusting
            if (_fuel < 0) {
                _fuel = 0;         // Make sure fuel amount doesn't go negative
            }
        }

        // Update the lunar lander's velocity and height. Also update the simulation clock (elapsed time).
        _vel += (GRAVITY + actualThrust) * TIME_STEP;
        _height += _vel * TIME_STEP;
        _elapsedTime += TIME_STEP;

        // Stop the simulation when height becomes zero or negative
        if (_height <= 0) {
            _height = 0;        // Make sure height does not go negative
            result = true;
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

Comment: So what actually happens?

Comment: Neither progress bar actually decreases as intended; they stay at 100%

Comment: Essentially what I'm trying to figure out is how to get the ProgressBar to update visually with the getFuel() and getHeight() methods

Comment: What actual values are you passing to `setProgress()`? Are they between 0.0 and 1.0?

Comment: I've updated my code with the method for how calculations are done. Both bars start at 1.0 but I'm not entirely sure how to decrease both bars to 0.0 and display that in the bar.

Comment: The value you pass to `setProgress(...)` [must be between 0 and 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ProgressIndicator.html#progressProperty--). So you just need to do the math to represent whatever value you intend to represent as a proportion (e.g. currentFuel/maxFuel or currentHeight/maxHeight, etc).

Comment: Oh my good, I feel so stupid for not figuring that out. Thank you immensely for your help. I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

In JavaFX, progressbar value should be >=0 & <=1

Means if you want 65% progress then you have to write code `progressBar.setValue(0.65);`

Assume `progressBar` is a valid initialized FXML progressbar.